# Hotpads Lead Post Callback with PHP

Tags: php, http, post, feed

I am trying to create a lead post callback for hotpads.

In the [documentation](https://hotpads.com/pages/partners/leadCallback.htm), it says it should return HTTP response. Does that mean that the it should just push something like:

`header("Location: URL", TRUE, 200);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,
in PHP is should look like this:
    header("HTTP/1.1 " . 200 . " success!" );